# pattern.dotall is not working in between \Q and \E

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression to fetch name and city from the input line.

example :

Hi David! how are you? are you in chennai now?

I need to fetch the david and chennai from this passage

I wrote the below code it is working fine but whenever there is line break in this line it is not working

```
package com.test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Passage : Hi David! how are you? are you in chennai now? "
                + "\n Hi Ram! how are you?\n are you in chennai now?";
        String regex1="\\QHi \\E(.*?)\\Q! how are you? are you in \\E(.*?)\\Q now?\\E";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex1,Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(result,m.group(1)+" is fine and yes I am in "+m.group(2));
        }
         m.appendTail(result);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Output :

Passage : David is fine and yes I am in chennai 
 Hi Ram! how are you?
 are you in chennai now?

Expected Output

Passage : David is fine and yes I am in chennai Ram is fine and yes I am in chennai

Note : I have used Pattern.DOTALL also.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think the problem is this line separator `you?\n are`, your pattern `\\Q! how are you? are you in \\E` doesn't account for it.

Comment: That `\n` is really what makes your regex fail. Use `\\s+` instead of the spaces and you cannot rely on `\Q....\E` here that much. Use `String regex1="Hi\\s+(.*?)\\s+how\\s+are\\s+you\\?\\s+are\\s+you\\s+in\\s+(.*?)\\s+now\\?";`

Comment: If you want to keep your current regex, you can do something like this: `p.matcher(input.replaceAll("\n", ""))` which will remove the line separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input can contain double spaces, or linefeeds/carriage returns instead of regular spaces, you should make use of the `\s` *whitespace* shorthand character class and that also means you *can't rely on `\Q...\E` that much in your pattern.

I suggest changing the regex with:

```
String regex1="Hi\\s+(.*?)\\s+how\\s+are\\s+you\\?\\s+are\\s+you\\s+in\\s+(.*?)\\s+now\\?";
```

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/Yt7tJH)

Output:

```
Passage : David! is fine and yes I am in chennai 
 Ram! is fine and yes I am in chennai
```

Comment: So, `Pattern.DOTALL` has nothing to do with what you have between `\Q...\E`. It only affects the `.` pattern that can match newlines. The literal spaces inside the pattern cannot match newlines. I hope that is clear.